# Find all critical points of $F(x,y) = (4y + x^2y^2 + 8x)/(xy) $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, problem-solving, maxima-minima

Here is what I have so far :

$$F_x (x,y) = \frac{((2xy^2)(xy) - ((4y + x^2y^2 + 8x)(y)))}{(xy)^2} \\ = \frac{x^2y^3 -4y^2 + 8xy - 8x}{(xy)^2}$$

And :
$$F_y (x,y) = \frac{((4 +2x^2y)(xy) - ((4y + x^2y^2 + 8x)(x)))}{(xy)^2} \\ = \frac{x^3y - 8x^2}{(xy)^2}$$

So I ended up using the quotient rule but this system seems difficult to solve is there a better way

Comment: for $$F_x=\frac{(2xy^2+8)(xy)-(4y+x^2y^2+8x)y}{(xy)^2}$$

Comment: You might want to rewrite $F$ as $$F(x,y)=\frac4x+xy+\frac8y$$ which makes the derivatives utterly trivial, as $$F_x=-\frac4{x^2}+y\qquad F_y=x-\frac8{y^2}$$ Critical points are by definition such that $F_x=F_y=0$, that is, $xy\ne0$ and $$x^2y=4\qquad xy^2=8$$ To solve this, note that $$(xy)^3=(x^2y)(xy^2)=4\cdot8=32=2^5$$ hence $$x=\frac{x^2y}{xy}=\frac{4}{2^{5/3}}=2^{1/3}\qquad y=\frac{xy^2}{xy}=\frac8{2^{5/3}}=2^{4/3}$$